# Get mouse coordinates on jqPlot for value

Tags: automated-tests, jqplot

I want to test jqPlot zoom automaticaly. I need to click one point and move mouse to other.
My plot looks similar to http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php but zooming is only possible for x axis.

So I need start and stop x coordinates to perform mouse actions.
Is there any function in jqplot that can convert time (which I show on x axis) to x coordinate?
I am using $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer for x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create plot with code:

```
plot = $.jqplot(...)
```

you can invoke:

```
plot.axes.xaxis.u2p(value)
```

on any axis